# CLion. Watch all values in debugger

Tags: c, debugging, clion

How can I watch all values in **CLion debugger** despite "optimized out" notification?

Now I have:

```
id = {int} <optimized out>
```

But I expect:

```
id = {int} 5
```

Comment: Disable all code optimization while debugging?

Comment: @Lundin how to do it?